# How to check if low is under a plot

Tags: charts, pine-script, indicator, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I have the following plot

```
last13 = lowest(close, 13)
Bottom = last13 == nz(last13[1]) ? last13 : na
plot(Bottom, color=#0000ff, linewidth=4, style=plot.style_linebr, title="Bottom", offset=0)
```

It will draw a short straight line on the chart.

I would like to count the number of bars where the line appears.

I want to check also if there is any low under or equal that short straight line, from the beginning of line. If yes, return true, if not, return false.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `var` counter for this.

```
var int bottom_counter = 0
bottom_counter := (not na(Bottom)) ? bottom_counter + 1 : 0
```